# Adafruit Trinket Analog Button Inputs

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, circuit-design, keyboard

I am using a Trinket's (not pro) analog inputs to read differing resistances from button presses. When any of the buttons are pressed, I want the internal LED to light up.

I have the buttons returning stable values, but the analog pin is inconsistently returning random results.

My board is set up as such: [image]

R4 isn't connected to my circuit as I am using pin 3 which has an internal pull_up.

```
#include <cmdline_defs.h>
#include <TrinketKeyboard.h>
#include <TrinketKeyboardC.h>
#include <usbconfig.h>

const int LED = 1;
const int analogPin = 3;
int value = 0;

void wait(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      delay(2);
      TrinketKeyboard.poll();
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(analogPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  TrinketKeyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  TrinketKeyboard.poll();
  value = analogRead(analogPin);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  wait();
  if(value > 612 || value < 609){ //these values are the default analog outputs for this pin on my board
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    wait();
  }
}
```

The TrinketKeyboard library can be found here: `https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Trinket-USB/`

Comment: How much do you expect it to change if the internal pullup is say 50k?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The amount of change between button inputs does not matter as long as it is detectable.

Comment: Quote https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins : The value of this pullup depends on the microcontroller used. On most AVR-based boards, the value is guaranteed to be between 20kΩ and 50kΩ. On the Arduino Due, it is between 50kΩ and 150kΩ. For the exact value, consult the datasheet of the microcontroller on your board.

Comment: Upload the basic sketch "AnalogInOutSerial" found under the example sketches, section "03.Analog". and modify the sketch value A0 to A3. Now you can measure the "Adafruit Trinket" values and confirm that the board works correctly.

Comment: I changed the input to analogPin 1, added a pullup resistor, and changed `pinMode(analogPin,INPUT_PULLUP);` to `pinMode(analogPin,INPUT);`. Its possible the built in pullup on pin 3 or the serial pin itself was faulty.